# How to mix levels of json coming out of jq

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

So I am trying to pull out some JSON with jq.

Here is an example:

```
{     
    "limit":10,
    "offset":20,   
    "values": [
       {
          "id": "abcd"
          "type": "file"
          "users": {
             "total": 2, 
             "profiles": [
                {
                     "first_name": "John", 
                     "last_name": "Smith"
                },
                {
                     "first_name": "Sue", 
                     "last_name": "Johnson"
                }
             ]
          }
       },
       {
          "id": "efgh"
          "type": "folder"
          "users": {
             "total": 1, 
             "profiles": [
                {
                     "first_name": "Steve", 
                     "last_name": "Gold"
                }
             ]
          }
       },
    ] 
}
```

I would love to get the following in my result

```
limit:10
offset:20
id:abcd, type:file, [users.total:2, users.profiles.first_name: [John, Sue], users.profiles.last_name: [Smith, Johnson]], 
id:efgh, type:folder, [users.total:1, users.profiles.first_name: [Steve], users.profiles.last_name: [Gold]],
```

I know I can pipe this to jq, but I don't know how.  I can get stuff in an array easily, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it and add in the top level elements.  So it's 'limit' and 'offset' that are throwing me fits.

I can get something out

```
jq ".values[] | .users.total, .users[].first_name, .users[].last_name"
```

But I cannot seem to figure out how to add in limit and offset.

Comment: You're missing a bunch of commas in your JSON.

Comment: Which version of `jq` are you doing this with? My 1.5.1 fails to parse this JSON due to missing and additional commas, and after fixing that, it fails with "Cannot index number with string "first_name""

Comment: It should be `.users.profiles[].first_name`

Comment: Sorry.  I posted just something made up on the fly, and trying to format it in stackoverflow so it looks decent made me forget the commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use commas at the top-level to get those fields. Use parentheses to group the expression that gets everything from `.values`.

```
jq '.limit, .offset, (.values[] | .id, .type, .users.total, .users.profiles[].first_name, .users.profiles[].last_name)'
```

[DEMO](https://jqplay.org/s/izjjHkDpdG)

Comment: This was it.  Is there a way for me to get jq to also print the JSON keys for each of these values as well?

Comment: Maybe you can do something with the `to_entries` function. It converts an object `{ "k1": "v1", "k2": "v2" }` to an array `[{"key": "k1", "value": "v1"}, {"key": "k2", "value": "v2"}]`. You can then loop through this to print the keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

> So it's 'limit' and 'offset' that are throwing me fits.

It looks like `to_entries` might be what you're looking for. Consider, for example:

```
to_entries[]
| select(.value | type != "array") 
| [.key, .value]
| join(": ")
```

With your JSON, this produces the lines you are having difficulty with, without any explicit mention of the key names:

```
limit: 10
offset: 20
```

You could then (for example) use the comma operator (`,`) to produce the other lines you want.